# C# - Dictionary of classes

Tags: c#, parsing, enums

I have a function that gets two strings - a key and a value.
I need to parse the value from string to enum.
the key represent which enum I need to use.
I wanted to use "if"s -

```
if (keyString == "e1")
{
    (MyEnum1)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum1), valueString, true);
} 
else if (keyString == "e2") 
{
    (MyEnum2)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum2), valueString, true);
} 
else if .....
```

But then I thought maybe I can create a dictionary of key and enum -

```
<"e1", MyEnum1>, 

<"e2", MyEnum2>,

...
```

and then use the dictionary's values for the enum parsing

```
    (dic[keyString])Enum.Parse(typeof(dic[keyString]), valueString, true)
```

but I couldn't do it..

I there any other way?

Comment: What you're doing with the parsed enum? Give some example. May be that can bring better.

Comment: It's not relevant to the question.

Comment: I believe it is relevant, You don't need to post original code. You can show some example. because I just need to know whether you need the enumtype as `Object` or strong type like `MyEnum2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store the type directly in the dictionary (i.e. store the result of `typeof(MyEnum1)`):

```
Dictionary<string, Type> KeyToEnum = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

KeyToEnum["e1"] = typeof(MyEnum1);
KeyToEnum["e2"] = typeof(MyEnum2);

Object EnumValue = Enum.Parse(dic[keyString), valueString, true);
// Note that EnumValue is an object, because we can't know at compile time what the type will be.
```

Note that if instead of "e1", "e2"... you actually had "MyEnum1", "MyEnum2" (i.e. the actual name of the type you could do `Type.GetType(MyKey)` instead of the dictionary.